# Can Django map multiple LDAP authentications onto a single User object?

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I am authenticating Django users against an Active Directory (LDAP) database using [django-auth-ldap](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/).

Our convention for `sAMAccountName` (typically the unique identifier for an AD account) is `firstname.surname`. It is possible that this value will change for a logical user. For example, their surname might change on marriage or divorce.

We are also requiring users to log in using their email prefix rather than their `sAMAccountName`, for ease of use. In the majority of cases, this value is the same as `sAMAccountName`. However, in some cases a user has two email addresses (1. legal name, 2. English/Western-friendly name). In other cases, email and `sAMAccountName` differ for historical reasons.

In all cases (AD identifier changes, two email identifiers for one user, email identifier != `sAMAccountName`) multiple valid LDAP authentications should map to the same logical Django user -- they should not trigger the creation of multiple, independent User objects.

How can we configure authentication for this scenario?

- **Aliases.** If it is possible to map a Django user onto a "Primary" user, rather than multiple authentications on the same user, that would be an acceptable solution.
- **Alternate libraries.** If another well-maintained Django/LDAP authentication library will do the job (e.g. [django-auth-ldap-ng](https://github.com/DheerendraRathor/django-auth-ldap-ng))

Comment: Nothing in Django would prohibit mapping multiple AD users to a single Django User. How you go about that depends entirely on the Django authentication backend that you're using.

Comment: @psagers updated question to mention backend (django-auth-ldap) - open to suggestions to switch it

Answer (score 1):

django-auth-ldap has a [documented mechanism](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/reference.html#django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend.get_or_create_user) to let you customize the user-creation process. By subclassing the backend and overriding this method, you can can map LDAP users to Django users any way you like.